# Replace application.properties placeholder with properties object values

Tags: java, spring

I have an instance of Properties class where the values are load via parameters passed by the command line using commons-cli library.

Ex.: java -jar app.jar -param1 valueofparam

So in Properties instance the param is set using properties.setProperty(“param1”,”valueofparam”)

In the other hand, the properties in application.properties are declared as follow:

app.param1=${app.param1}

How can I load the Properties object into application.properties to start spring configuration after SpringApplication.run(…,args)?

Thanks.

Comment: You can directly set the value by using `--app.param1=[value]`. Setting this value by command line should take precedence over other property sources. [Spring externalized configuration docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-command-line-args)

Comment: Instead of passing arguments to the jar, you should make use of the features offered by spring to make your life easier

Comment: I think spring allows you to also set it as a System property like so `-Dapp.param1=value` then it should be picked up by the placeholder `${app.param1}`

Comment: I cannot do that because the requirements of the project doesn’ allow it. The quid is to replace application.properties placeholders with Properties instance values set with setProperty method.